# How to convert dataframe to Seq in Zeppelin(Scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I want to convert my dataframe to Seq in Zeppelin.

My Dataframe is as below

```
+--+-------+-----+
|id| charid| name|
+--+-------+-----+
| 1|     a1|   ad|
| 2|     a2|  agf|
| 3|     a3|  ged|
| 4|     a4|  nom|
| 5|     a5| scal|
| 6|     a6|  tip|
| 7|     a7|  low|
+--+-------+-----+
```

So how can I convert this to Seq as below.

Seq[Long, (String, String)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `map` and `toSeq`?

```
val result = df.select($"id".cast("long"), $"charid", $"name")
               .rdd
               .map(row => (row(0).asInstanceOf[Long], (row(1).asInstanceOf[String], row(2).asInstanceOf[String])))
               .collect
               .toSeq
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collect` and `toSeq` to convert to Seq, Make sure your dataset is small enough to fit in the driver node

```
df.rdd
  .map(r => (r.getLong(0), (r.getString(1), r.getString(2))))
  .collect()
  .toSeq
```

Or

```
df.collect
  .map(r => (r.getLong(0), (r.getString(1), r.getString(2))))
  .toSeq
```

Comment: I was thinking of this at the beginning, but it throws an error of `java.lang.String incompatible with java.lang.Long` on my machine...

Comment: @mck Can you provide the schema of your dataframe ?

Comment: thanks, I saw what's wrong, my schema has int type. I edited my answer to cast the columns to long type to prevent problems, coz I'm not sure what the OP's schema look like.